# Installing 2 separate Versions of Flutter at the same time on a Device?

Tags: android, flutter

Is it possible to install 2 versions of my flutter up at the same time on my device? Imagine I run `flutter run --profile` to install my app on my device, then I update something/switch branches and now I would wan't to install the new version separate to the old version to compare them on my device. Is that possible somehow? I'm using android btw if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, if you can create product flavours in Android.

- In `android/app/build.gradle`
  Add:

```
    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors {

        app1 {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.example.app1"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        app2 {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.example.app2"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
```

Then run `flutter run --flavor app1` or `flutter run --flavor app2`

There is a detailed guide detailing ever step that also includes giving each their own name in the phone launcher https://cogitas.net/creating-flavors-of-a-flutter-app/